# Discord.net run separate shards for the same bot on multiple physical servers

Tags: discord.net

I am in the process of expanding my infrastructure for one of my Discord bots. Planning ahead there will become a point at which I cannot keep all the shards on one server. I am moving my database to a separate server and would like to be able to split up the servers the bots shards are on as well.

I would ideally like to get an idea where to start by generating separate Discord Bot Client users and figuring out how the DiscordShardedClient works.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this, and if yes can you add that as answer?